# Load CSV and split attributes

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to load a csv file and split 'timespan' into 'begin' and 'end'. If the timespan consists of one date 'begin' and 'end' are the same.

```
timespan,someOtherField, ...
27.03.2017 - 31.03.2017,someOtherValue, ...
31.03.2017,someOtherValue, ...
```

**Result**:

```
begin,end,someOtherField
27.03.2017,31.03.2017,someOtherValue, ...
31.03.2017,31.03.2017,someOtherValue, ...
```

At the moment I'm loading the file line by line using OpenCSV. This works pretty good but i don't know how to split one attribute. Propably I have to parse the CSV into an array?

Comment: If the date sizes are constants, can you rely on splitting them with the " - "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any line `l` you can use `StringTokenizer` to get the tokens separated by `,`:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(l, ",")
```

The first token represents `timespan`, so:

```
String timespan = tokens.nextToken()
```

Then you can split timespan based on `" - "`, so:

```
String[] startEnd = timespan.split(" - ");
```

Finally, you have to compute the size of the `startEnd`, if `startEnd.length == 1`, then you absolutely know that start `begin` and `end` coincides, so `startEnd[0],startEnd[0]`

otherwise the result would look like the following `startEnd[0],startEnd[1]`

I hope this could help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! I parsed the csv into an extra class and created an object for each record. The code below shows the splitting of the timespan. I will now rebuild a new csv file from all objects.

```
// Load CSV as Booking objects
    ArrayList<Booking> bookings = Utils.readCSV(csvClean);

    for (int i = 0; i < bookings.size(); i++) {
        String timespan = bookings.get(i).getTimespan();
        String begin = "";
        String end = "";

        if (timespan.contains(" - ")) {

            // Split timespan and set values
            String[] parts = timespan.split(" - ");
            begin = parts[0].trim();
            end = parts[1].trim();

            bookings.get(i).setBegin(begin);
            bookings.get(i).setEnd(end);

        } else {
            bookings.get(i).setBegin(timespan.trim());
            bookings.get(i).setEnd(timespan.trim());
        } // end if else

    } // end for
```